# How to correctly instance a IPython cluster made of local and remote machines

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, ipython

I'm facing big problems in instancing a cluster for IPython. I think the doc is pretty complicated.

My system is made of the following things:

1. Local computer, Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64, IPython 2.1, 8 cores processor
2. Remote computer, Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64, IPython 2.1, 16 cores processor, access through passwordless SSH from local computer.

I have access with no password to the remote server via ssh `linello@myserveripaddress`.
I think this situation is pretty standard for many people that carry scientific computations.

I want to instanciate an IPython notebook with 8 local and 16 remote engines (=24 total engines) to exploit for some embarassingly parallel computations.

If I start my ipython cluster with a `ipcluster start` and then start an IPython instance, where I instanciate the `Client` class, I just get only 8 local clients

```
In[1]: from IPython import parallel
In[2]: clients  = parallel.Client()
In[3]: print clients.ids
Out[3]: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

This means that only the local engines started. So I modified my `ipcluster_config.py` script to the following:

```
c = get_config()

c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SSH'
c.LocalControllerLauncher.controller_args = ["--ip='myserverip'"]

c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {
    'localhost': 4,
    'tyler': 4,
    'par': 4,
}


c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engine_cmd = ['/ipengine']
```

where `myserverip` is actually my server ip `192.168.xxx.yyy`

I really don't know how to correctly configure my ipython profile to do have 24 engines in my ipython kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I found this really confusing in the beginning as well.  I still do to some extent, but I think I have a case working that looks similar to yours.

The only thing that looks to be missing is telling the engines where the controller is.  There's an option in the ipcluster config that looks like:

```
c.SSHEngineLauncher.engine_args = ['--location=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the ip address of the machine running the controller.  I *think* that's the likely issue with your config.

I usually test this sort of thing by running ipcluster from the prompt.  It's usually fairly explicit about the problem.  I hope that helps.

Also, I usually don't need to specify:

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engine_cmd = ['/ipengine']
```